# Can't resolve dependency for jsoup

Tags: java, gradle, jsoup

I'm creating a news downloading gradle project with the following directory structure.

```
news-feed (root)
|-bbc-plugin (sub-project)
```

I want to use the jsoup library for my sub-projects so I add the dependency to my root build.gradle file as follows.

```
import org.gradle.api.artifacts.*

apply plugin: 'base' // To add "clean" task to the root project.
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'newsFeed.MainMenu'

subprojects {
    apply from: rootProject.file('common.gradle')

    apply plugin: 'java'

    dependencies {
        compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':bbc-plugin')
}
```

I can't build the project because of the error

```
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':bbc-plugin:compileClasspath'.
> Can't resolve external dependency org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3 because no repositories are defined.
  Required by:
      project :bbc-plugin
```

Is there are way to specify the dependency in the root build file without having to specify in the build.gradle file of each sub-project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell gradle from which repository it can download your dependency. To achieve this, you need to add a `repositories` section to your build script.

To use Maven Central, for instance, you need to add the following lines to your to root build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

See [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html#sec:declaring_your_dependencies) and [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:repositories) in the Gradle user guide for a more detailed description.

Comment: I tried changing my code like so but I'm still getting the same error `subprojects {
    apply from: rootProject.file('common.gradle')
    
    apply plugin: 'java'
    
    dependencies {
        compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'
    }
    
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}`

Comment: Oh, my fault. You need to apply the `repositories` section to the root project not only to the subprojects. I've updated my answer.